# Search on a Huge table with Full text search

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search, sqlperformance

I have a table "subscriber" (with 500 million rows) that has about 20 columns, in my App I let to the user search for his subscribers by Email, Firstname or Lastname

So I created a FullText Index with this three columns

```
CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG [SubscribersCatalog] WITH ACCENT_SENSITIVITY = OFF
GO
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON [dbo].[Subscriber]
    ([Email] LANGUAGE 1033, [FirstName] LANGUAGE 1033, [LastName] LANGUAGE 1033)
    KEY INDEX [PK_Suscriber]
    ON ([SubscribersCatalog], FILEGROUP [Subscriber]);
```

The Subscriber table has Id which is PK and UserId as FK

When I execute this query

```
select *
from dbo.subscriber s
where contains(email,'*keyword*')
and s.UserId = 92651
```

It took too long, so I look with the live plan and this is what I got.

[image: Live plan]

It's getting about 80k rows because is for all users and then filters to the desired user, but maybe the desired user only has 1 row as result... if I put a common keyword it is worse.

I created this to avoid to user LIKE '%keyword%' but in some situations the performances is worse than create index with UserId, Email and do a Like.

How I can change the FullText index or the query to improve performance?

Comment: do you have an index on UserId?

Comment: Not an answer to your original question, but it might be worth looking into a dedicated search solution like ElasticSearch. In my experience it's really hard to make full text search scale in SQL Server.

Comment: Yes to ElasticSearch or predecessor like Lucene if you were using Java say on the back end.

Comment: What @NickBailey has said. I'd really recommend to move to Elasticsearch for such queries in order to avoid bigger performance and scalability problems.